# lodash does omit mutate the array on which it is called?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, lodash

Looking at `filter` method of lodash, it was unclear to me by docs whether this method mutates the collection on which it is called.

But it appears that in react, when I try to make a new collection from previous properties and `_.omit` does mutate the parent.

Is `_.reject` a more proper solution which does not mutate its parent?

here is an example jsfiddle of profile.id dissapearing.
https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/96535/

Comment: Omit is used on objects, not arrays. filter will not mutate the collection.

Comment: Functions which mutate their input are explicitly called out as such in the docs (Ctrl+F "mutate" in https://lodash.com/docs). Neither `filter` nor `omit` have any mention of mutating the input.

Comment: @EricGuan docs say omit is to be used on objects https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omit

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin I have added a jsfiddle example showing profile.id disappearing

Comment: I don't see any usage of lodash at all in your jsfiddle.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin link was broken should be fixed now

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely follow your question, but it appears you are concerned with whether one or more of `filter`, `omit` or `reject` mutate their input. None of them do. Run this snippet to see:

```js
const original = {a: 1};

console.log('--- filter() ---')
console.log(_.filter(original, 'a'));
console.log(original);

console.log('--- omit() ---')
console.log(_.omit(original, 'a'));
console.log(original);

console.log('--- reject() ---')
console.log(_.reject(original, () => true));
console.log(original);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Shameless plug: [`filter()`](https://simontonsoftware.github.io/micro-dash/typedoc/index.html#filter) and [`omit()`](https://simontonsoftware.github.io/micro-dash/typedoc/index.html#omit) are available in my library [Micro-dash](https://github.com/simontonsoftware/micro-dash), with a much smaller bundle size than their Lodash counterparts.

Comment: Is there a version of `omit` in lodash that mutates the object?

Comment: Looks like [`unset()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#unset) may be what you want for that.

Comment: @EricSimonton Got one question about micro-dash, does it support chaining methods like lodash 'chain' does? If yes, then how can we do it?

Comment: @asdasd No, it does not. It is only loose functions (which makes it very tree-shakeable)